# Is it a clean way to write this function?

Tags: linq

I had to write a function or functions that returns accounts by role, by currency, by company, by application type. I decided to make one function that according to the request model returns filtered accounts. My question: Is it a clean way to implement the function?

```
public List<ResponseModel> Get(RequestModel requestModel)
{
    return (from role in Context.UserRoles
            where
                role.UserId == requestModel.UserId &&
                role.Account.CompanyId == requestModel.CompanyId &&
                (requestModel.RoleId == null ? true : role.RoleId == requestModel.RoleId) &&
                (requestModel.Currencies.Count() == 0 ? true : requestModel.Currencies.Contains(role.Account.Currency)) &&
                (requestModel.ApplicationTypes.Count() == 0 ? true : requestModel.ApplicationTypes.Contains(role.Account.Type)) &&
                (requestModel.AccountUse == null ? true : role.Account.AccountUse == requestModel.AccountUse) &&
                (requestModel.OperationTypeId == 0 ? true : role.OperationTypeId == requestModel.OperationTypeId) &&
                !role.Account.IsDeleted &&
                !role.Account.Company.IsDeleted
            orderby role.Account.FormattedAccount
            group role by role.Account into Accounts
            select new ResponseModel
            {
                Id = Accounts.Key.Id.ToString(),
                FormattedNumber = Accounts.Key.FormattedAccount,
                Number = Accounts.Key.Number,
                Currency = Accounts.Key.Currency,
                Application = Accounts.Key.Application
            }).ToList();
}
```

I was thinking write a store procedure that returns the same but there are almost 250 SP on the sql server and this function is used a lot.
I also thought split it in small functions but I don't know hot to do it.

If this helps:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int OperationTypeId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId {get; set;}
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AccountUse { get; set; }
    public List<string> Currencies { get; set; }
    public List<string> ApplicationTypes { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What's "unclean" about the current implementation?  If you're just looking for a code review, there's a Code Review SE site specifically for that.

Comment: What part of  your method is not clean in your opinion?

Comment: I think the linq sentence is too big...and I was wondering if there is other way to write it

Comment: @JesusPocoata: the length of a LINQ query doesn't say anything about it's correctness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct, easy to read and understand, and its execution side is probably as fast as it gets.

The only thing that I would adjust is the conditionals of the form

```
someCondition ? true : someOtherCondition
```

I would replace them with an equivalent

```
(someCondition || someOtherCondition)
```

to remove conditional expressions from the `where` clause. I would also replace `collection.Count() == 0` with `!collection.Any()`, as follows:

```
return (from role in Context.UserRoles
        where
            role.UserId == requestModel.UserId &&
            role.Account.CompanyId == requestModel.CompanyId &&
            (requestModel.RoleId == null || role.RoleId == requestModel.RoleId) &&
            (!requestModel.Currencies.Any() || requestModel.Currencies.Contains(role.Account.Currency)) &&
            (!requestModel.ApplicationTypes.Any() || requestModel.ApplicationTypes.Contains(role.Account.Type)) &&
            (requestModel.AccountUse == null || role.Account.AccountUse == requestModel.AccountUse) &&
            (requestModel.OperationTypeId == 0 || role.OperationTypeId == requestModel.OperationTypeId) &&
            !role.Account.IsDeleted &&
            !role.Account.Company.IsDeleted
        orderby role.Account.FormattedAccount
        group role by role.Account into Accounts
        select new ResponseModel
        {
            Id = Accounts.Key.Id.ToString(),
            FormattedNumber = Accounts.Key.FormattedAccount,
            Number = Accounts.Key.Number,
            Currency = Accounts.Key.Currency,
            Application = Accounts.Key.Application
        }).ToList();
```

In order to keep the interpretation of various `RequestModel` properties inside the `RequestModel` class you could provide a `Filter` property, as follows:

```
public class RequestModel {
    ...
    public Expression<Func<UserRole,bool>> Filter {
        get {
            return role =>
                (role.UserId == UserId)
            &&  (role.Account.CompanyId == CompanyId)
            &&  (RoleId == null || role.RoleId == RoleId)
            &&  (!Currencies.Any() || Currencies.Contains(role.Account.Currency))
            &&  (!ApplicationTypes.Any() || ApplicationTypes.Contains(role.Account.Type))
            &&  (AccountUse == null || role.Account.AccountUse == AccountUse)
            &&  (OperationTypeId == 0 || role.OperationTypeId == OperationTypeId);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your `where` clause like this:

```
return (from role in Context.UserRoles.Where(requestModel.Filter)
        where !role.Account.IsDeleted && !role.Account.Company.IsDeleted
        orderby role.Account.FormattedAccount
        group role by role.Account into Accounts
        select new ResponseModel {
            Id = Accounts.Key.Id.ToString(),
            FormattedNumber = Accounts.Key.FormattedAccount,
            Number = Accounts.Key.Number,
            Currency = Accounts.Key.Currency,
            Application = Accounts.Key.Application
        }).ToList();
```

Note how all conditions related to `requestModel` are "hidden" inside the `RequestModel` instance. This would make future modifications to `RequestModel` easier, because you wouldn't need to make "parallel modifications" in other parts of the code.